# Adding flask-security-too routes to OpenAPI documentation generated by flask-smorest

Tags: flask, flask-smorest

To set up OpenAPI with flask-smorest, you need to import Api from flask_smorest, and pass Api the flask_app object. Then you use method register_blueprint to register blueprints, and that's it.

```
from flask_smorest import Api
api = Api(flask_app)
api.register_blueprint(some_generic_bp)
```

I'm wondering whether it is possible, and if so, how I can add the API routes generated by flask-security-too to the API documentation generated by flask-smorest? After setting up Security object in app, Flask app object registers the 'security' blueprint, so it seems that using api.register_blueprint() is out of the question.